# Use o método split() e if para criar uma declaração que imprima as palavras que começam com 's'

Tags: python, if, split

Eu tenho a seguinte string:

```
string_1 = 'Print only the words that start with s in this sentence'
```

e preciso utilizar o método split e um if para ter como saída apenas as palavras iniciadas em s.
Mas não faço ideia de como fazer isso. Help me??

Comment: Comece utilizando o método `split`. Sabe como utilizá-lo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o método `split` para separar as palavras dessa forma: `string_1.split(" ")`. Depois disso percorra todas as palavras da lista e verifique se o primeiro elemento (primeiro letra) é um "s". Exemplo:

```
string_1 = 'Print only the words that start with s in this sentence'
lista_de_palavras = string_1.split(" ")
for palavra in lista_de_palavras:
    if "s" == palavra[0]:
        print(palavra)
```

Caso queira palavras que comecem com a letra "s" independentemente de serem maiúsculas ou minúsculas, você pode utilizar o método `lower()` e verificar se a primeira letra é igual a "s" minúsculo. Exemplo:

```
string_1 = 'Print only the words that start with s in this sentence'
lista_de_palavras = string_1.split(" ")
for palavra in lista_de_palavras:
    if "s" == palavra.lower()[0]:
        print(palavra)
```